# Why dont I need to memoize maxHeight in the problem below

Tags: dynamic-programming, c++

I see this occasionally when solving Dynamic programming questions. I like to solve dp questions using recursion, then Memoize it based on the number of parameters I pass to the recursive function.
The question is, in my code below, even though I passed three parameters to my recursive function, the solution still worked when I Memoized only two parameters. 
I want to understand why this works (memoizing only two parameters instead of three still produces the correct answer). Thanks

Below is the link to the question. 
https://leetcode.com/problems/filling-bookcase-shelves/

> You are given an array books where books[i] = [thicknessi, heighti] indicates the thickness and height of the ith book. You are also given an integer shelfWidth.
>  We want to place these books in order onto bookcase shelves that have a total width shelfWidth. We choose some of the books to place on this shelf such that the sum of their thickness is less than or equal to shelfWidth, then build another level of the shelf of the bookcase so that the total height of the bookcase has increased by the maximum height of the books we just put down. We repeat this process until there are no more books to place. 
> Note that at each step of the above process, the order of the books we place is the same order as the given sequence of books.
> For example, if we have an ordered list of 5 books, we might place the first and second book onto the first shelf, the third book on the second shelf, and the fourth and fifth book on the last shelf.
> Return the minimum possible height that the total bookshelf can be after placing shelves in this manner.

Below is my code.
the logic behind my code is:

> For each book we have two choices: 
>  Either 1) place it in the current shelf or 2) place it in a new shelf. 
>  Find the minimum from those two options. If we place it in a new shelf, we have to add the height of the previous shelf to the return value.

i.e minH(int curBook, int maxHeight, int curWidth) returns the minimum shelve height attainable using Book[curBook] to Book[N] where N is the number of books.
curBook is the current Book we are on, maxHieght is the maximum height we have seen on the current Shelve excluding the height of curBook, and curWidth is the current width of books placed on the current shelve excluding the width of curBook.

```
class Solution {
public:
    int dp[1001][1001];
    vector<vector<int>> books;
    int shelfWidth;
    int minHeightShelves(vector<vector<int>>& books, int shelfWidth) {
        this->books      = books;
        this->shelfWidth = shelfWidth;
        return minH(0, 0, 0);
    }
    
    int minH(int curBook, int maxHeight, int curWidth){
        if(curBook >= books.size())
            return maxHeight;
        else if(dp[curBook][curWidth])
            return dp[curBook][curWidth];
        else{
            int ans = maxHeight + minH(curBook+1, books[curBook][1], books[curBook][0]);
            if(curWidth+books[curBook][0] <= shelfWidth){
                int Height = max(maxHeight, books[curBook][1]);
                ans = min(ans, minH(curBook+1, Height, curWidth+books[curBook][0]));
            }
            dp[curBook][curWidth] = ans;
            return ans;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: It would be better if you edit your post to include the problem you are trying to solve, instead of just linking the source. Also, give a short explanation of your solution, instead of just the code.

Comment: @Russel I added a bit more information let me know if I am missing anything else. Thanks for the input.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://stackoverflow.com/q/72512491/781723, https://cs.stackexchange.com/q/152097/755. Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1):

Memoization does not affect correctness.  It only affects the running time.  An algorithm that is correct with memoization will also be correct without memoization, and vice versa.  Memoization doesn't change what result the algorithm returns, it only changes how long it takes to get to that result.

Comment: I do agree that memoization only speeds up the time complexity, but my question is how is this algo still working even though i am memoizing only two of the three parameters.

Comment: @African_king, I already told you how: memoization doesn't affect the result, so if it is working with memoization, it will be working without memoization too, and vice versa.  I see that [PaulMcKenzie already told you the same thing, too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72512491/why-dont-i-need-to-memoize-maxheight-in-the-problem-below#comment128094298_72512491).